# OpenMP parallel for bug

Tags: c++, for-loop, openmp

I am currently working on a tutorial on OpenMP where the following example was given and the author claims that it contains a Bug (The result is not correct). However, I cannot spot it:

```
#pragma omp parallel for private(temp)
for(i=0;i<N;i++)
{
  for (j=0;j<M;j++)
  {
    temp = b[i]*c[j];
    a[i][j] = temp * temp + d[i];
  }
}
```

For me there is no bug as `temp`, `i` and `j` are private and the loop over `j` is executed sequentially ... Am I missing something ?

Comment: `i` and `j` are not private, aren't they? Or at least `j`? Could you provide the tutorial?

Comment: The OpenMP compiler/run-time takes care of privatising `i`.  But the inner loop, over `j` is not parallelised so `j` is not made `private`.  Either try `for (int j=0;j<M;j++)` instead or include `j` in the list of private variables.

Comment: Maybe as tip, I always use  `default(none)` so the compiler warns you about not declared variables

Comment: It is just on a pdf slide I copy pasted the code. And the only other text is "Spot the bug." But now I see that  `i` and `j`  where not defined in the for loop statements so this might be the problem as `j` is not `private` then !

Comment: Yes thanks a lot @RoQuOTriX !!! You opened my Eyes ... ... ...

Comment: Ok yes got it ... I was Blind .. Thank you all :-)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the previous comments the variables `i` and `j` are not declared in the loop statements. As the compiler takes care of the loop variable `i` by setting it to private but not `j`, the inner loop variable is shared thus falsifying the result. One way to correct it would be:

```
#pragma omp parallel for default (none) private(temp, i, j) shared(a, b, c, d)
for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
  for (j = 0; j < M; j++)
  {
    temp = b[i] * c[j];
    a[i][j] = temp * temp + d[i];
  }
}
```